# Haskell types and signatures

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, integer

I'm studying for an exam about Haskell. I don't understand how I determine the type of a function. The function is:

```
func [] f = 16
func (h : t) f = (f h) + (func t f)
```

My guess is that the first line has this types: `empty list -> a -> a` where `a` has to be a numeric type. In Haskell notation `Num a => [] -> a -> a` and the second line has this types: `[a]-> a -> ?` What does it return? Maybe `(a, a)` because  `(f h)` is a tuple. What about `(func t f)`, is `a` or? And how do I mix both lines together?

Comment: @soon thanks for the edit, it is more readable this way

Comment: You are always welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (easy) way to find out about such problems is to write it in a file and load it into `ghci` and issue the command `:t func`, which is nice while preparing for an exam but not applicable during it - so I will walk you through the hints that can be found.

As @soon gave a perfectly valid answer - I will only add a few hints you might use in the future:

determine the number of arguments (this might be a bit difficult if the function is written in pointfree style, i.e. `func x = const x` could be written as `func = const`.

so in this case we get two arguments and one result so we can write the signature as

```
func :: ? -> ? -> ?
```

1. Look for results (in this case `16`) and determine its type
   you already noticed that `16` is something numerical - thus

   ```
   func :: Num a => ? -> ? -> a
   ```

   looks as a good starting point.
2. Look for type constructors that help you identify ADTs or `type`/`newtype`s in your function.

   Now in the first and second case we have two hints that the first argument is of type list (`[]` and the constructor `(:)`) gives us this info. As we have no information about the contents of the list we have to assign a different type variable for them - `b`.

   ```
   func :: Num a => [b] -> ? -> a
   ```
3. identify functions used to determine the rest or get more specialized types for the stuff you already found out

   here we have 2 informations one is the `(+)` operator, and `(f h)` - as the whitespace character in haskell means function applicaton we get `h`'s type has to be the domain of the function `f` and as the result of `f h` is used with `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` (Note that both arguments must have the same type, as well as the result) and the result of `func t f` (which is `a`) we get  the target type of `f` and therefore `f :: b -> a`

composing this we get

```
func :: Num a => [b] -> (type-of-f) -> a
func :: Num a => [b] -> (b -> a) -> a
```

Comment: ok may I do it for another function, `func2 1 (h : t) = h ; func2 n (h : t ) = func2 (n-1) t` . `func2 :: Num a => a ->[b] -> b` for the first line because 1 is a numerical type,(h : t) is a list and h is the first element of the list. The second line is `func2:: Num a=> a -> [b] -> ?` Maybe the result of the first line which is b? So the complete thing would be `func2::Num a => a ->[b] -> b`. Is that correct?

Comment: Seems to be quite correct, except the base case '1' implies an instance of `(Eq a)` it seems, I think that's because you could translate this expression in an `if (n == 1) …then…else` expression

Comment: btw - you can type the `func2` definition in a file - load it into ghci with ghci myfile.hs and then `:t func2` in order to see wether your reasoning is correct

Answer (score 6):

```
func [] f = 16
```

This line defines a function `func`, accepting a list and `f`, and  returning `16`. The type could be written as `Num a => [b] -> c -> a`.

```
func (h : t) f = (f h) + (func t f)
```

This line restricts `f` type to `Num a => b -> a`, because:

1. `f` should accept an element from the list
2. `f ...` should return a value, which could be added to result of `func ...`

So, the type of `func` is:

```
Num a => [b] -> (b -> a) -> a
```

Comment: ok thank you, so in (f h) haskell calls f with the parameter h and then it adds the result to the result of `code`( (func t f) )? Is that correct?